# Understanding the Clausius-Clapeyron equation

Tags: thermodynamics, phase-transition

I am confused about what the Clausius-Clapeyron equation is saying basically. I learned it from *Finn's Thermal Physics* textbook. Here is the illustration they used to derive it.

[image]

Matter of two different phases can only coexist when they have the same specific gibbs function.

At A,

$$g_1(T,P) = g_2(T,P)$$

And at B,

$$g_1(T+dT,P+dP)=g_2(T+dT,P+dP)$$

I'm not sure why this is necessarily the case, but Finn merely states this.

From the previous equation, via a Taylor expansion and the thermodynamics identity for G,

$$v = \left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial P}\right)_T$$

$$s =  -\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial T}\right)_P$$

Then, a way to rewrite the equation
$$g_1(T+dT,P+dP)=g_2(T+dT,P+dP)$$
is

$$\frac{dP}{dT} = \frac{\Delta S}{\Delta V} $$

Then, with $L = T \Delta S$,

$$\implies \frac{dP}{dT} = \frac{L}{T \Delta V}$$

The mathematics of arriving from the equation in terms of specific gibbs functions and to the final result is fine with me, but I don't actually know what this represents. To me, it is one of two things:

1. It is either the rate of change of pressure with temperature such that a substance remains on a phase boundary and does not transition
2. Or it informs how the volume and entropy change from a phase transition based on its signature.

But, to be honest I really have no idea what this is. I understand the mathematics but not the underlying principles here.

For instance, for these two graphs:

[image]

Would following along the lines where it says $\frac{dP}{dT} > 0$ or $\frac{dP}{dT} < 0$ be the lines one would have to follow to not change phase? Or, for instance, is the $\frac{dP}{dT} > 0$ in (a) showing the effects of volume and entropy (that the volume and entropy would increase) for melting would account for a $dP/dT$ that is positive here?

Comment: The derivation is only concerned with points along the boundary. So the relation just talks about the boundary line, right?

Comment: Did you really want to focus on the SL equilibrium, or are you more interested is LV equilibrium?

Comment: @AaronStevens I believe so.

Answer (score 2):

Some would call the equation that you have derived the Clapeyron equation and if one of the phases is a gas they would call it the Clausius-Clapeyron equation.

> I am confused about what the Clausius-Clapeyron equation is saying basically.

The equation is telling you about the slope of the pressure against temperature graph when two phases coexist with one another.

If $L$ and $\Delta V$ do not change by very much over a certain temperature range then integrating your equation gives $P_2-P_1 = \dfrac {L}{\Delta V}\ln{\dfrac{T_2}{T_1}}$ so if you have knowledge of one point on the graph, $(P_1,T_1)$, the (Clausius-)Clapeyron equation enables you to find other points $(P_2,T_2)$.
In other words the prssure and the temperature are not independent of one another.

Comment: Is it the required behavior of pressure with temperature required for two phases to coexist?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not sure why this is necessarily the case, but Finn merely states this.

For a mixture of two phases in equilibrium, when mass of the phase 1 is $m_1$ and that of phase 2 is $m_2$, the total Gibbs free energy $$G(T,P)=m_1g_1(T,P)+m_2g_2(T,P)$$ must be at its minimum. Using $m_1+m_2=\text{constant}$, and the fact that for an infinitesimal transfer of mass from one phase to another, the change in $G(T,P)$ must be zero i.e. $$dG(T,P)= dm_1~g_1(T,P)+dm_2~ g_2(T,P)=0,$$ one obtains (since $dm_1=-dm_2$) $$g_1(T,P)=g_2(T,P).$$

> 1. It is either the rate of change of pressure with temperature such that a substance remains on a phase boundary and does not transition
> 2. Or it informs how the volume and entropy change from a phase transition based on its signature.

If $\frac{dP}{dT}>0$, it implies that the with the increase in pressure the melting point increases and if $\frac{dP}{dT}<0$, with the increase in pressure, the melting point decreases.

Comment: I still don't understand. Why does $\frac{dP}{dT} > 0$ imply an increasing pressure implies increase in melting point? What does increasing pressure constitute on a $PT$ diagram? Going up or down along an isotherm?

Comment: If I have a value for $\frac{dP}{dT}$, how do I what Wikipedia does to find the pressure needed to melt ice at $-7$ Celsius?

The Wikipedia link I'm referring to is at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausius%E2%80%93Clapeyron_relation#Example